# How to get help for a function of a module in REPL of node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to get some Documentation basically Man pages for a function belonging to a module in node.js using REPL.

Console.dir(modObj) lists down all the method and properties which belongs to a module. Furthermore, i am not able to find any Manual or help against the function which will demonstrate examples and the usage of the function.

The same is pretty straightforward in Python Interactive Shell as follows. Looking through Official Online Documentation of a module is one alternative. Does REPL have the inbuilt support for Man pages for all the modules?

In Python Interactive Shell:-

```
import os
dir (os)
['EX_CANTCREAT', 'EX_CONFIG', 'EX_DATAERR', 'EX_IOERR', 'EX_NOHOST', 'EX_NOINPUT', 'EX_NOPERM', 'EX_NOUSER', 'EX_OK', 'EX_OSERR', 'EX_OSFILE', 'EX_PROTOCOL', 'urandom', 'utime', 'wait', 'wait3', 'wait4', 'waitpid', 'walk', 'write']
help(os.walk)
Help on function walk in module os:

walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)
    Directory tree generator.

    For each directory in the directory tree rooted at top (including top
    itself, but excluding '.' and '..'), yields a 3-tuple

        dirpath, dirnames, filenames

    dirpath is a string, the path to the directory.  dirnames is a list of
    the names of the subdirectories in dirpath (excluding '.' and '..').
    filenames is a list of the names of the non-directory files in dirpath.
    Note that the names in the lists are just names, with no path components.
    To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in
    dirpath, do os.path.join(dirpath,name).
```

In REPL of Node:-

```
> var fs=require('fs')
undefined
> console.dir(fs)
{ Stats: [Function],
  F_OK: 0,
  R_OK: 4,
  W_OK: 2,
  X_OK: 1,
  access: [Function],
  accessSync: [Function],
  exists: [Function],
  existsSync: [Function],
  readFile: [Function],
  readFileSync: [Function],
  close: [Function],
  closeSync: [Function],
  open: [Function],
  openSync: [Function],
  read: [Function],
  readSync: [Function],
  write: [Function],
  writeSync: [Function],
  rename: [Function],
  renameSync: [Function],
  truncate: [Function],
  truncateSync: [Function],
  ftruncate: [Function],
  ftruncateSync: [Function],
  rmdir: [Function],
  rmdirSync: [Function],
  fdatasync: [Function],
  fdatasyncSync: [Function],
  fsync: [Function],
  fsyncSync: [Function],
  mkdir: [Function],
  mkdirSync: [Function],
  readdir: [Function],
  readdirSync: [Function],
  fstat: [Function],
  lstat: [Function],
  stat: [Function],
  fstatSync: [Function],
  lstatSync: [Function],
  statSync: [Function],
  readlink: [Function],
  readlinkSync: [Function],
  symlink: [Function],
  symlinkSync: [Function],
  link: [Function],
  linkSync: [Function],
  unlink: [Function],
  unlinkSync: [Function],
  fchmod: [Function],
  fchmodSync: [Function],
  chmod: [Function],
  chmodSync: [Function],
  fchown: [Function],
  fchownSync: [Function],
  chown: [Function],
  chownSync: [Function],
  _toUnixTimestamp: [Function: toUnixTimestamp],
  utimes: [Function],
  utimesSync: [Function],
  futimes: [Function],
  futimesSync: [Function],
  writeFile: [Function],
  writeFileSync: [Function],
  appendFile: [Function],
  appendFileSync: [Function],
  watch: [Function],
  watchFile: [Function],
  unwatchFile: [Function],
  realpathSync: [Function: realpathSync],
  realpath: [Function: realpath],
  createReadStream: [Function],
  ReadStream:
   { [Function: ReadStream]
     super_:
      { [Function: Readable]
        ReadableState: [Function: ReadableState],
        super_: [Object],
        _fromList: [Function: fromList] } },
  FileReadStream:
   { [Function: ReadStream]
     super_:
      { [Function: Readable]
        ReadableState: [Function: ReadableState],
        super_: [Object],
        _fromList: [Function: fromList] } },
  createWriteStream: [Function],
  WriteStream:
   { [Function: WriteStream]
     super_: { [Function: Writable] WritableState: [Function: WritableState], super_: [Object] } },
  FileWriteStream:
   { [Function: WriteStream]
     super_: { [Function: Writable] WritableState: [Function: WritableState], super_: [Object] } } }
undefined
>
> help(fs.stat)
ReferenceError: help is not defined
    at repl:1:1
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:252:27)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:417:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:549:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:826:14)
```

Comment: You can read the `node.js` official docs at https://nodejs.org/api/.

Comment: That is the whole point.  Without official documentation can we find the desired information using REPL? There are times when the internet connectivity is slow or intermittent at those times Interactive shell is the only option to fetch the information.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think node provides it's docs in REPL as of now. There is an issue opened for the same thing in node's official repo, you can check it out [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8493)

There is a tool in npm though which can serve your need [node-help](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-help)

But if you are happy with just bringing the docs offline, then I can recommend some tools.

- [DevDocs](https://devdocs.io) - It can be used to save docs of various languages right into your browser.
- [ZealDocs](https://zealdocs.org) - If you are not comfortable with opening your browser everytime, then this utility can help you.

Comment: ZealDocs is a good alternative. Let me try node-help also. Thanks for sharing the valuable information.

Comment: Glad to know it helped :)